# How can my extension stop a rickroll before the video starts playing?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make an Chrome extension that stops rick rolls! my manifest.json looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "AntiRick",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Say hello to AntiRick, say goodbye to RickRolls!",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "rick.png"
    },
    "icons": {"16": "rick.png", "48": "rick.png", "128": "rick.png"}
}
```

and my content.js looks like this:

```
var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
    
video.pause();
```

this extension stops the video **BUT** only after one second! is there any way i can stop the video from playing so you hear nothing from the rickroll?
There are no errors in this code!

Answer (score 0):

Set `run_at` in manifest to `"document_start"` or `"document_end"`.

If you choose `"document_end"` the script should work as it is.

If you choose `"document_start"` the DOM doesn't loaded yet so you'll probably need to wrap the script with

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // your code goes here
})
```

You can read more about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_scripts#run_at)

Comment: i added this code but it now doesnt stop the video! what can i do else?

Comment: At all or immediately ?

Comment: once it stoped the video but the other times nothing happend